# What's wrong with my change calculator?

Tags: ruby

```
puts "Welcome to the change calculator. Give me a dollar value, and I will give you the least number of coins equal to that amount."
dollar = gets.to_f
quarters = dollar / 0.25
remains1 = dollar % 0.25
dimes = remains1 / 0.10
remains2 = remains1 % 0.10
nickels = remains2 / 0.05
remains3 = remains2 % 0.05
pennies = remains3 / 0.01
puts "Your change is #{quarters.to_i} Quarters, #{dimes.to_i} Dimes, #{nickels.to_i} Nickels, and #{pennies.to_i} Pennies."
```

It should give the change in coins, but something is wrong with the rounding. For example, when I put in $ 2.32 it outputs "Your change is 9 Quarters, 0 Dimes, 1 Nickels, and 1 Pennies." It should be 2 pennies. What's wrong?

Comment: Floating point math is inexact. Convert the input amount to cents and use integers.

Answer (score 0):

Floating-point numbers cannot precisely represent all real numbers, and floating-point operations cannot precisely represent true arithmetic operations, this leads to many surprising situations.

I advise to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

You can solve most of this problems by using `BigDecimal` instead of floats

```
require 'bigdecimal'
#...
dollar = BigDecimal.new(gets)
#...
```